# Add Header row to multiple .txt files using

Tags: python

Python newbie hoping I can get a little bit of help. I have a bunch of .txt files listing GPS data. I would like to create a python script that will open each .txt file in the directory and add headers (prior to converting to .csv and then processing as ESRI GIS feature classes). I have some python code that will list the .txt files in my target directory and I also have some python code that will add the headers to a single specified .txt file but I am not sure how to tie the two bits of code together so the whole script will process all the .txt files

**Python Code to list .txt files:**

```
import glob

Workspace = "C:\\Pathway\\ToTarget"
date = time.strftime('%y_%m_%d')
Directory = Workspace + "\\" + date

glob.glob(Directory + "./*.txt")
```

So, if i do

```
import glob

Workspace = "C:\\Pathway\\ToTarget"
date = time.strftime('%y_%m_%d')
Directory = Workspace + "\\" + date

listoffiles = glob.glob(Directory + "./*.txt")
print listoffiles
```

I get a list of the .txt files in my target directory. So far all good.

================

**Python to add header to a specified .txt file**

```
listoffiles = "C:\\Pathway\\to\\Target_Dir\\Log - Copy (2).txt"
headers = "SENT_ID,TIME_UTC,NAV_WARN,LAT,N_S,LONG,E_W,SPEED,COURSE,DATE,MAG_VAR,,CHECK".split()

for line in fileinput.input([listoffiles], inplace=True):
    if fileinput.isfirstline():
        print '\t'.join(headers)
    print line,
```

This changes the first line of the specfied .txt file. All Good.

================

**Amalgamated Code**

However if i do this:

```
import glob
import fileinput
import os
import time   

Workspace = "C:\\Pathway\\ToTarget"
date = time.strftime('%y_%m_%d')
Directory = Workspace + "\\" + date

listoffiles = glob.glob(Directory + "./*.txt")
headers = "SENT_ID,TIME_UTC,NAV_WARN,LAT,N_S,LONG,E_W,SPEED,COURSE,DATE,MAG_VAR,,CHECK".split()

for line in fileinput.input([listoffiles], inplace=True):
    if fileinput.isfirstline():
        print '\t'.join(headers)
    print line,
```

The error that I get is: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

```
  Message   File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
<module>    C:\Users\pennychr\Desktop\GPS_2.py  58      
next    C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\fileinput.py 253     
readline    C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\fileinput.py 318     
"TypeError: can only concatenate list (not ""str"") to list"
```

If anyone can give me some pointers as to the correct way to help me work around this issue, that would be great.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the **full text** of the traceback. It contains valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was an error trying to generate the `listoffiles` list using `glob.glob()`. Following with your previous concatenations to create the directory string, I'd suggest replacing that line with the following:

```
listoffiles = glob.glob(Directory + "\\*.txt")
```

and see if that works. You've been using Windows filepaths all along, yet `'./*.txt'` is UNIX-style for "all files ending in `.txt` in the current directory." This doesn't work in your situation, because it adds a `.` to the end of `Directory` before the `\\*.txt` part.

When debugging, it's often extremely helpful to either run through your code line-by-line in IDLE, IPython, or another utility, checking your variable's values at each step. Alternatively, put in a `print` statement after every variable assignment to check what its current value is, and to ensure it conforms with what you think it should be.

In addition to the above error, something else caught my eye:

```
headers = "SENT_ID,TIME_UTC,NAV_WARN,LAT,N_S,LONG,E_W,SPEED,COURSE,DATE,MAG_VAR,,CHECK".split()
```

does not do what you think it does. The `string.split()` function, when not given any arguments, splits on whitespace, which is not present in your input. Therefore, your `print '\t'.join(headers)` statement later on isn't doing anything except converting the single-item list `headers` back into a string (with no tabs, BTW). Observe:

```
>>> "SENT_ID,TIME_UTC,NAV_WARN,LAT,N_S,LONG,E_W,SPEED,COURSE,DATE,MAG_VAR,,CHECK".split()
['SENT_ID,TIME_UTC,NAV_WARN,LAT,N_S,LONG,E_W,SPEED,COURSE,DATE,MAG_VAR,,CHECK']
```

It just returns a single-item list with the full string as its only member. However, splitting on comma `,` yields:

```
>>> "SENT_ID,TIME_UTC,NAV_WARN,LAT,N_S,LONG,E_W,SPEED,COURSE,DATE,MAG_VAR,,CHECK".split(',')
['SENT_ID', 'TIME_UTC', 'NAV_WARN', 'LAT', 'N_S', 'LONG', 'E_W', 'SPEED', 'COURSE', 'DATE', 'MAG_VAR', '', 'CHECK']
```

which is what I suspect you were trying for. This is yet another reason for always carefully checking your variables and your output.

Comment: Although your amendment makes the pathways to the .txt files correct (`'C:\\GIS_Projects\\GPS_Tracking\\14_06_27\\Log - Copy (10).txt'` and opposed to `'C:\\GIS_Projects\\GPS_Tracking\\14_06_27.\\Log - Copy (10).txt'`), I am still getting the same `"TypeError: can only concatenate list (not ""str"") to list"`

Comment: @biggins - what is Line 58 in your code? From the traceback, that's where the error is occurring.

Comment: Hi matt, thanks for the info about the `string.split()` it's always good to know about these things. I have been using pyscripter and usually run a `print` just to get an idea what a variable is doing. In this instance, if i go through the process the `header` as I have written it (if it's at the top of the .txt file) is correct once I convert to .csv and then open in ESRI ArcCatalog.

Comment: Line 58 corresponds to the first line of the amalgamated code posted in the OP `for line in fileinput.input([listoffiles], inplace=True):`

Comment: @biggins - so if you're converting to CSV, you really don't need a tab-separated header string...

Comment: @biggins do you have write access to that directory?

Comment: 1) Strictly speaking, no but it's a nice to have for onward processing of the data into GIS environment. 2) Yep, I have write access to the target directory.

Comment: As a tangent. This code does almost exactly what i want but it writes the headers to the 2nd line of the text file `for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob(Directory + '\\*.txt'), inplace=True):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace('sit', 'SIT'))
    if fileinput.filelineno() == 1:
        #adds new line and text to line 1
        sys.stdout.write('SENT_ID,TIME_UTC,NAV_WARN,LAT,N_S,LONG,E_W,SPEED,COURSE,DATE,MAG_VAR,,CHECK' '\n')`

[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731511/how-to-modify-all-text-files-in-folder-with-python-script?lq=1)

Comment: @biggins It's writing to line 2 b/c Python indexes are generally 0-based.

Comment: Yep, i tried changing it to 0 but then the code doesn't write anything to the .txt file.